# How to include all items in Tkinter Treeview?

Tags: tkinter, treeview

I tried to create a treeview to include all of items but I keep getting error messsage: as follows:

***"in insert
res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index,
_tkinter.TclError: Item ADC already exists"  Please advise me how to include all of items in the treeview?"***

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree["columns"] = ("one")
tree.column("one", width=50)


data = ['Test/SubTest_1/Area1/Measurement1/ADC/Voltage',\
        'Test/SubTest_1/Area1/Measurement2/ADC/Voltage']


def append_to_tree(node, c):
    if not c:
        return

    if c[0] not in node:
        node[c[0]] = {}

    append_to_tree(node[c[0]], c[1:]) 

hierarchy = {}

for path in data:
    append_to_tree(hierarchy, path.split('/'))

def add_node(k, v):
    for i, j in v.items():
        tree.insert('', 1, i, text=i)
        if isinstance(j, dict):
            add_node(i, j)

for k, v in hierarchy.items():
    tree.insert("", 1, k, text=k)
    add_node(k, v)

tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You used the content of each sub-node as the *iid* of the row, so there will be two rows with same *iid* "ADC" which is not allowed.  Better use the default *iid* generated by treeview instead.  Also you insert all the items under the *root* node, is it what you want actually?

Comment: I am trying to make it look like this:

Test -> Area1 -> Measurement1 -> ADC -> Voltage
Test -> Area1 -> Measurement2 -> ADC -> Voltage

in the same treeview diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the content of each sub-node as the *iid* of the row, so there will be two rows width same *iid* "ADC" (also "Voltage") which is not allowed.

Better to use the default *iid* generated by treeview instead:

```py
def add_node(k, v):
    for i, j in v.items():
        iid = tree.insert(k, 'end', text=i) # save the iid
        if isinstance(j, dict):
            add_node(iid, j)  # used the generated iid

for k, v in hierarchy.items():
    iid = tree.insert('', 'end', text=k)
    add_node(iid, v)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What about adding the checkbox and print the path on the shell?

Comment: @user9362225 It is new requirement which is better to create another question.